# how to save Audio Volume to playerprefs to mute all scenes sounds

Tags: unity, sound

Please Explain me how to Save or Set Audiolistner or scene Audio to playerprefs to control game all scene sound by a simple Button On and Off ..

Please Give Me C sharp Script as a Example To Mute and UnMute Full Game All Scenes Sound from Scene 1.

Thanks ..Waiting

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First of all you need to use is the pattern below to control all the scene's sounds in one place:

-Create a **MusicManager** class. It would better be singleton.

-Initialize an object from this class, and use DontDestroyOnLoad() in order to keep musicmanager alive when scene changes;

-Declare a static methods like:

- `public static void PlaySound(AudioClip clip);`
- `public static void SetVolume(float volume);`
- public static void Mute(){audioSourceObject.volume = 0f;}

-Then when it comes to play any audio, use these methods for playing sound by giving the sounds as a parameter.

-Also when it comes to mute just call the mute function.

For saving purposes:

```
PlayerPrefs.SetFloat("soundVolume", currentVolume);  //Note that you need to keep the volume in a variable called currentVolume or whatever you name it.
```

And also when the game starts, put the code below in MusicManager class' `void start()` method:

```
currentVolume = PlayerPrefs.GetFloat("soundVolume");
SetVolume(currentVolume);    //This function has been defined above
```

By doing these, if the player mutes the game, the musicmanager will set the volume to 0f, then save it as 0f when the game gets closed. And also be re-set as 0f when the game is opened again.

Hope this helps!

Comment: Your'e absolutely welcome!